# How to update an image on button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

When I click on 'apply_but' button I want the picture on this button to be updated. But it doesn't work.
Another problem is that when I open this window - "Noise insertion" also method "curves" works and opens another window with label "What are u looking for?". But this method should work only after clicking on "img_but" button.

```
class Noise(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, pic):
        super().__init__()

        w = self.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - 300  # ширина экрана
        h = self.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - 300  # высота экрана

        self.geometry('600x600+{}+{}'.format(w, h))

        self.title('Noise insertion')
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self['bg'] = '#7be8cf'

        Label(self, text='Noise insertion', font=('Comic Sans MS', 20),
                       fg='#3d3d42', bg='#7be8cf').place(x=200, y=0)

        var = IntVar()
        var.set(0)
        var2 = IntVar()
        var2.set(0)

        self.yes_but = Radiobutton(self, text="Yes", variable=var, value=0,
                               font=('Comic Sans MS', 20),
                               width='10', height='1', activebackground='#e6f547',
                               bg='#7be8cf')
        self.no_but = Radiobutton(self, text="No", variable=var, value=1,
                              font=('Comic Sans MS', 20),
                              width='10', height='1', activebackground='#e6f547',
                              bg='#7be8cf')
        self.salt_but = Radiobutton(self, text="salt and peper", variable=var2, value=0,
                                font=('Comic Sans MS', 20),
                                width='10', height='1', activebackground='#e6f547',
                                bg='#7be8cf')
        self.gauss_but = Radiobutton(self, text="gauss noise", variable=var2, value=1,
                                 font=('Comic Sans MS', 20),
                                 width='10', height='1', activebackground='#e6f547',
                                 bg='#7be8cf')
        self.scale = Scale(self, orient=VERTICAL, from_=0, to=100, bg='#7be8cf',
                       activebackground='#e6f547', font='10',
                       highlightbackground='#7be8cf', label='%', fg='#f53be2')
        self.apply_but = Button(self, text='Apply', font=('Comic Sans MS', 10),
                            width='15', bg='grey', fg='white', bd=20, command=self.update_pic(pic))

        self.img_but = Button(self, image=pic, command = self.curves())

        # Pack()
        self.yes_but.place(x=0, y=100)
        self.no_but.place(x=0, y=50)
        self.salt_but.place(x=220, y=50)
        self.gauss_but.place(x=220, y=100)
        self.scale.place(x=500, y=50)
        self.apply_but.place(x=220, y=200)
        self.img_but.place(x=150, y=300)

    def update_pic(self, pic):
        var = self.scale.get()
        scale_res = self.scale.get()
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(get_pic('color_dragon.jpg', size= 
                              (300,200)).filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur))
        #self.img_but[image] = self.img ???

        pass

    def curves(self):
        Curves()
        pass

class Curves(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        w = self.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - 300  # ширина экрана
        h = self.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - 300  # высота экрана

        self.geometry('600x600+{}+{}'.format(w, h))

        self.title('Curves')
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self['bg'] = '#7be8cf'

        Label(self, text='What are u looking for?', font=('Comic Sans MS', 20),
                       fg='#3d3d42', bg='#7be8cf').pack()
```

Comment: `command = self.curves()` should be `command = self.curves` and you can also say in the `update_pic()`  `self.img_but.image = self.img`

Comment: @CoolCloud if I say `self.img_but.image = self.img` then I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'Noise' object has no attribute 'img_but'.` And using `command = self.curves` didn't help. I still get this window opened before clicking the button.

Comment: i actually asked to remove the `()` from the method and what is wrong with `self.img_but[image] = self.img` ?

Comment: i dont use OOP much so i dont knw what the problem with the attributes are but try `img_but.image = self.img` instead of `self.img_but.image = self.img` and it should also be `command=lambda: self.update_pic(pic)`

Comment: @CoolCloud first I get `Unresolved reference 'image'  and then the same mistake `AttributeError: 'Noise' object has no attribute 'img_but'`

Comment: oh sorry, i actually dont know whats the problem there, but anyway the buttons part should be should remove the `()` and if you to pass arguments then use `lambda: self.update_pic(pic)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Commands shouldn't call functions directly** - instead, they should name the function to be called when activated.

Try replacing this: `command=self.update_pic(pic)`

With this: `command = lambda pic=pic: self.update_pic(pic)`

And this: `command = self.curves()`

With this: `command = self.curves`

Comment: Yeah, that works. Now another window doesn’t open before time. But what about image? How to update it?

Comment: Well, this part would be easier for me to test if i could see the full code... But maybe try adding `self.img_but = Button(self, image=self.img, command=self.curves)` at the end of the `update_pic` function, and then using the `.update_idletasks` or `.update` methods of the `tkinter.Tk()` object.

Comment: `.update` and `.update_idletasks` didn't work. But placing one button above another works))) `self.img_but = Button(self, image=self.img, command=self.curves).place(x=150, y=300)` adding this at the end of the `update_pic`

Comment: Great! Then I'll appreciate it if you chose my answer. You can even edit it to include the solution you found, for the benefit of others in the future :) @EugeneKartashev